# Differences between C and C++: array size is not honored

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I'm learning C++ and I found a behavior I don't understand. If I write the following program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char question[] = "What is your name? ";
    char answer[2];
    printf(question);
    scanf("%ls", answer);
    printf("%s\n", answer);
    return 0;
}
```

When I type a name longer than two bytes the answer is something gibberish, but even if I don't know exactly why, I know that something went wrong and it tried to recover.
Instead, if I write this C++ program (somewhat equivalent to the former):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char question[] = "What is your name? ";
    char answer[2];
    cout << question;
    cin >> answer;
    cout << answer << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'd expect a similar behavior, since I declared `answer` as a char array and not a string (which can adjust its size dynamically). But when I type something very long, it is printed back as I entered it. An example:

```
$ ./test
What is your name? asdfa
asdfa
$ ./test
What is your name? sdhjklwertiuoxcvbnm
sdhjklwertiuoxcvbnm
```

So, what's going on here? As a secondary question, what happens in the C one, when I type something longer?

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, I know I can use `std::string` instead of char arrays (I had written it above ^^). I was interested in knowing why the programs exhibited *that* behavior. Now I know it's undefined behavior. Also, I corrected the error in the C program (scanf).

Comment: In C you have to allocated enough space. In C, strings are just "arrays of chars". The so-called Giberish is That you are actually reading data from an invalid memory "area".

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what the *actual* behavior for the C program is, like you do with the C++ program?

Comment: This question isn't related to arrays. You need to use scanf() correctly. See chapter 1 of any beginner-level C programming book.

Comment: If you're using c++, you shoudl probably be use `std::string` and things like `std::getline(std::cin, mystring)`

Comment: @Lundin: yes, I noticed that it's not correct, I was going by memory.

Comment: One thing to remember about C: C puts the power into the hands of the programmer.  If you want to write some buggy crap... you can! ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is undefined behavior (UB):

```
scanf(answer);
```

`scanf` function will interpret the uninitialized content of `answer` as the *format string*, causing UB.

It should be like this:

```
scanf("%1s", answer);
```

Note that when you declare a character array of size 2, it means that it could fit a C string of length at most 1, because you need one character for null terminator.

Note that when you enter more than two characters for the name in your C++ program, you get undefined behavior too: writing past the end of the array is UB. Fortunately, it is very rare to need to read a string into a character array in C++, because the standard C++ library supplies a dynamically resizing class `std::string`, a much better choice for representing strings.

Answer (score 12):

`char answer[2];` means your array can contain only 2 characters. if you push more than that, the memory is overrun and it is undefined behavior. Either reserve enough space in the array, or better use `std::string` if using array is not mandatory. And you are taking input in wrong way as the other answer pointed out.

Comment: "your array can contain only 2 characters" ... and one of them has to be `'\0'` for it to be a string.

Comment: To elaborate, "undefined behavior" means anything can happen.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot expect similar behaviour.

You can expect *undefined behaviour* in both cases: overrunning your memory buffer is *undefined behaviour* in both languages, so absolutely anything is allowed to happen.

Comment: If only the old "[nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)" approach was taken by more compilers, developers might be more cautious.

Comment: I never heard the nasal demons reference.  I wonder if Biff suffered from them....

Answer (score 1):

`char answer[2];` contains space for just 2 bytes. (1 byte + 1 `NUL` character in case of `NUL` terminated string)

In both `C` and `C++` accessing data beyond the array size is [undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So you should now ask `why`, `how` etc. You should just not do that.

Correct way to handle this undefined behaviour would be:

- In C allocate enough space in memory (Or use fread not to read enough
  space the array can digest)
- In C++, use `std::string`